# ASP.NET Core MVC application in container not working in Chrome but comes up in Firefox. Redirecting to signin-oidc

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My web application is an ASP.NET Core MVC app, and I working to containerize it and deploy it on a K8 cluster. I am facing issues around redirection. I am using Azure AD authentication. In my `Startup.cs`, I am redirecting the URL to https. But it seems that on Chrome and Edge my site is redirecting to `/signin-odic` page. It works in Firefox but not as consistently.

This is my `startup.cs` code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, (OpenIdConnectOptions options) =>
        {
            options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
             options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                string redirectUri = "https://" + context.Request.Host + "/signin-oidc"; 
                AzureAdAppSettingsHelper.RedirectUriSuffix;
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = redirectUri;
                context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri;
                context.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);
            };

        });

    var redisConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("redcache");

    _redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);

    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        }).AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions => jsonOptions.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);

    services.AddKendo();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddScoped<ICacheService, CacheService>();
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_CONNECTIONSTRING"]);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Err");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Ins",
            pattern: "Ins/{*Home}",
            defaults: new { controller = "ins", action = "Home" });
        });
}

private async static Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext ctx)
{
    var claims = new ClaimsPrincipal();
    const string AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE = @"https://graph.windows.net/";

    var credential = new ClientCredential(ctx.Options.ClientId, ctx.Options.ClientSecret);

    string userId = ctx.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

    var cache = new adowebhub.Controllers.RedisTokenCache(ctx.Options.ClientId, userId);
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ctx.Options.Authority, cache);
    var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(ctx.ProtocolMessage.Code, new Uri(ctx.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri), credential, resource: AZUREADGRAPH_RESOURCE);
    ctx.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);
}
```

When I try from Chrome I get this error in the logs:

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
>
> System.Exception: Correlation failed.

In Firefox sometimes I get this error, but mostly it works:

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.

Please suggest

---

So I was able to get Chrome working now with below code in my Startup.cs file.

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        });
```

However if I am using 2 pods in my K8 cluster and requests hit separate pods I am getting error

> System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
> System.Exception: Unable to unprotect the message.State.

Comment: I believe Chrome is a little more strict when it comes to sending cookies.  Samesite=none cookies must be sent securely.   Does the error ever occur when you browse directly to the https url or only when redirecting from http to https?  (http/https can also be different servers in some configurations...so they can be considered different domains in some situations)

Comment: So when I run the site as regular https it works fine for running is docker I have end point set as http and the redirect it to https  to make it secure

Comment: not sure I understand... why wouldn't it be secure all the way through? (really has nothing to do with your question, but seems odd to do it this way)

Comment: Have you used `app.UseHttpsRedirection(); ` in your program.cs file? If not, please add it,  the order should be app.UseHttpsRedirection();  -> app.UseDefaultFiles(); -> app.UseStaticFiles();...

Comment: By the way, if it not works, pls capture the http trace, I mean the har file, let us check the logs in chrome(not work) and fireforks (when it works), it will help us find the different. I believe it's code issue, not related to browsers.